# How to make sql request in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, request, distinct, query-builder

I have a working request in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, articul FROM products WHERE category_id=40 order by articul;
```

How can I do this request in Laravel with the right format using a query builder? And how must the method of the model be?

First I have tried using this code:

```
$products = Product::orderBy('aerucul')
    ->select('articul', 'id', 'name')
    ->distinct()
    ->where('category_id', 40)
    ->get();
```

But I got duplicates.

If I try to use this, the result is the same:

```
$products = DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT id, name, articul FROM products WHERE category_id='40' order by articul");
```

Comment: The literal SQL query and the Eloquent query are literally the same thing... you can replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and see the literal generated SQL query that Eloquent is going to run. What is the "_duplicated_" data? What column too?

Comment: column 'articul' in some products  has a same values. I want to show only 1 row of same 'articun' value....

Comment: You have to show data (not as an image), because `distinct` will already filter the same values... You did not mentioned if the first query in your question is returning the expected data

Comment: For example 23456 Item1 size M | 23456 Item 1 size L, i wont's to shew only 1first Item  (23456 it's a articul )

Comment: I am very ignorant about this, but I think that, because none of the 3 are identical, they are not going to be excluded. As you saw, you have 2 `size`s so it will never remove the second one. What you can try using is `group by articul`, so it is unique 100%

Comment: first SQL request in PhpMyAdmin work perfect...

Comment: Thanx, all working with GroupBy but i have correct some in config/database.php

Comment: What did you have to change? The `strict` mode, right?

Comment: Yes, that's help me..

Answer (score -1):

try using `DB::table()` method

```php
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->select('id', 'name', 'articul')
    ->distinct()
    ->where('category_id', '=', 40)
    ->orderBy('articul')
    ->get();
```

If you want to get only 1 product, instead of `->get()` use `first()`

Comment: Read the comments, he solved the issue by using `groupBy` instead of distinct... Your query is exactly the same as his...